# Developer Certificate is no longer valid but app was approved by Apple

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store-connect

In our team a developer **send app to review**.

It went through but **at some point developer certificate was no longer valid**.

**We're now not able to download app in external or internal testers**.

**What will happen if we release that version**?

I will appreciate your experiences and opinions.

Comment: Since you need a distribution cert to send the app to Apple, the development cert is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Developer certificate is just that, for development.  When submitting an app to the app store you are signing the application with **distribution** profile.

So to answer your question, if you have a valid distribution profile nothing will happen when releasing the app to the store.

Comment: Once sent to Apple for review, it doesn't even matter what happens to the distribution profile either.